# Systemd timer that expired while suspended

Tags: systemd, suspend, systemd-timer

I have created a systemd user timer that expires daily, i.e. at midnight. The problem is that my computer is normally suspended at night. When I wake it up in the morning, I want the timer to trigger, but that doesn't happen. I discovered the Persistent option, but that only helps when the system is powered down, since it triggers expired timers when starting the services. Is there a solution to this other than e.g. running an hourly timer and saving a timestamp to a file somewhere?

Edit 2017-03-17:
I'm using systemd 231 on ubuntu 16.10.
What I want to is to run [remind](https://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind) once a day, preferably when I wake up the computer in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no problem with the `Persistent` option and suspend. The problem seems to be that `Persistent=true` only works if the timer has had a chance to trigger at least once, i.e. if **LAST** is not **n/a**. But my computer is normally suspended at midnight, so the timer has never triggered.

Answer (score 3):

One option you have is to set `WakeSystem=true` in your `.timer` file, which will wake the computer from suspend to run the job.

Then in the `.service` file that's run, you can add:

```
 ExecStopPost=sudo /bin/systemctl suspend
```

To re-resuspend the computer when the job is done running.

You'll also need to update `/etc/sudoers` to allow your user to run the above command without requiring a password.

---

A second option is to use one of the monotonic timers described in `man systemd.timer` like `OnActiveSec=`. These timers stop counting time when the computer is suspended. These allow you to express things like "Please backup my computer  once every 8 hours that it is on". If your computer is normally on about 8 hours a day, this will roughly correspond to once per day.  As you describe, your computer is frequently backed up around midnight anyway-- it's backed up when you first unsuspend it in the morning.

---

Third, did you confirm that `Persistent=` doesn't work with `suspend` as well when the machine is powered off?

Comment: We'll since I only want to use remind to show a desktop notification, it seems excessive to wake up the computer for that. Also, I would like to get the reminder first thing in the morning, so the OnActiveSec doesn't help with that. I confirmed that Persistent was enabled with systemctl show. I suspended the computer last evening and it hasn't fired today either. List-timers says n/a for last expiration time.

Comment: I think you should file a bug with `systemd`: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues I believe that either: 1. `Persistent=` should work through suspends or 2. the document for `Persistent=` should be updated to reflect that it doesn't "Persist" through suspends.