# Crontab jobs during suspend will not run?

Tags: linux, cron, suspend, xubuntu

Environment: Linux XUBUNTU 22.04.2 LTS on an ACER ASPIRE laptop.
Tools: Using Linux Text Editor to create a bash script also tried
using crontab to execute each command a minute apart.
Goal: To have the machine wake from suspend, run a cleanup, and go back to suspend.

What I have tried: 3 seperate crontab lines one minute apart: rtcwake then Bleachbit then suspend. This failed to launch in suspend mode. Next I wrote a bash script calling

```
rtcwake; bleachbit --clean --preset; suspend
```

and assigned a crontab job to run it. That failed too. It seems that crontab goes to sleep on suspend. Is that true? And all of this was tried from root so it is not a permissions issue. Also the script was confirmed set to executable. Any ideas?

Comment: Of coursde, `crond` doesn't run during suspend. Nothing runs during suspend. But: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/351967/32191

Comment: The link was helpful, but "Nothing runs during suspend" is not accurate. If this were true, nothing would be monitoring for a "lid open" signal and perform the wakeup. Yes some things are needed to maintain responiveness durring suspend. I just wasnt sure if crontab was one of them. I see it is not.

Comment: That is like saying "Something must be running while the computer is powered-off as otherwise pressing the power button would not turn it on..."

Comment: Now you are confusing hardware and software? Good greif. Anyone else?

Comment: Yeah, I obviously confused your lid with hardware; how could that happen... Enjoy your time here. We love smart people.

Comment: Hauke - You are offensive and rude. You have nothing useful to say. I did not say my lid was invovlved and it is not. For your information, this machine is being put into suspend mode with the lid open. The lid is not the issue. Please take your attitude somewhere else. If this place  is for smart people, what are you doing here?